# How to configure Quarkus with Oracle Database after importing quarkus-hibernate-orm?

Tags: hibernate, datasource, quarkus

What is driver name to be given in quarkus application?

```
quarkus.datasource.ergoint.driver=org.xxx.xxx.Driver
```

If it does not provide native support then how can we fix this adding dependency in maven project?

**Note**: On official website nothing mentioned related to Oracle -> https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#multiple-datasources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment, there is no Oracle specific extension inside Quarkus, but there is an open issue for it you can +1 on it : https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/1658

If you need to use Oracle database, you can do it the same way you did for othe framework: add the dependency inside your pom.xml (easy now that Oracle provides them in Maven central) and configure it inside the application.properties

In your case it should be

```
quarkus.datasource.ergoint.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

If you need to deploy your application as a native image, you will need some work to make the Oracle driver works, you can find some information here: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1748

Comment: Thanks. If not native, Will it work fine in jvm mode?

Comment: Yes, as Oracle DB is working in HIbernate it should work (I said should as I didn't test it by myself)

Comment: It worked for me when i added things like ->  quarkus.datasource.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver AND THEN
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver AND THEN
quarkus.datasource.ergoint.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: Do we have to define persistance.xml file in this case?

Comment: @Erfankam using or not `persistence.xml` is orthogonal from this issue. We advise to avoid using it unless it's realy required.

Answer (score 0):

Here started to work with the following:

```
    quarkus.datasource.db-kind=other
    quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
    quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1521:XXXXX
    quarkus.datasource.username=USERNAME
    quarkus.datasource.password=PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 0):

In release 1.13.2.Final the support for oracle has been added.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-oracle</artifactId>
</dependency>

quarkus.datasource.db-kind=oracle
```